# how to put controller/action in link_to rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

`<%= button_to '+',{:controller=>"line_items",:action=>'create',:menu_id=> line_item.menu_item,:remote=>true}%>`

I have put same code for link:

`<%= link_to '+',{:controller=>"line_items",:action=>'create',:menu_id=> line_item.menu_item,:remote=>true}%>`

But `link_to` is redirect me to the line_item_index page.I want that link_to will work like this button.please help me i am new in rails.

Comment: what does your log file say!! does it render as JS! i am not sure but i don't see the {} in http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to use controller/action and not resource routing with helpers?

Answer (score 2):

link_to uses http GET for the resource you're linking while button_to uses http POST to your controller action.
adding `:method => :post` explicitly to your link_to tag makes it behave as http POST event

Answer (score 0):

method `link_to` creates link and method `button_to` creates form. They are not the same.
From `button_to` you are using the form with method POST and it works ok, but with `link_to` you are using method GET, and this is a problem.

To solve the problem, try this:

```
link_to '+',{:controller=>"line_items",:action=>'create', :menu_id=> line_item.menu_item, :remote=>true, method: :post}
```

more explanation at:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to